# Detecting Notification Balloons

Tags: windows, system-tray, popup-balloons

Using WinXP. What I need to do (pref in VB or c#) is to detect when another (closed source) program displays a notification balloon in the tray - and grab the details. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So what have you tried and what happened?

Answer (score 1):

In similar situations, I have used the Microsoft tool Spy++ to grab the window information and then uses pinvoke calls to `FindWindow` to detect when the window is present.

I've not tried with a notification balloon, but I imagine that a pinvoke call to `GetText` would retrieve the contents.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to use pinvoke to do this from a .net language.

On the system I'm using now (Vista Business SP2), balloon windows always seem to have window class [#32769](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633574%28VS.85%29.aspx) (reserved for desktop windows) and the windows style bit TTS_BALLOON set.

The following *might* work: Determine the parent window for all notification balloons by creating a temporary one, getting its hWnd, and calling [GetParent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633510%28VS.85%29.aspx) before deleting it. You could then periodically poll the children of this parent hwnd (using [EnumWindows()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [FindWindowEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500%28VS.85%29.aspx)) looking for windows with the required class and style.

This seems highly non-portable to me, and likely to require a lot of testing on a variety of platforms.

[pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/) and spy++ might be useful.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely need to use Win API calls to achieve this.  If this is the only thing you're trying to do, you'd be better off using straight C or C++ so you don't have to do a bunch of platform invoke for C# or VB.

Since [andyjohnson identified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109078/detecting-notification-balloons/2110085#2110085) that the window class for all notification balloons is #32769, and that they have the `TTS_BALLOON` style set, you could use a [CBT hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977(VS.85).aspx) (if you're not familiar with Win32 hooks, you might want to [read up on them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997537.aspx)), to get a callback whenever a window is created, and check for windows of that class and with that style.

I'm not sure, though, if a new balloon window is created for second and subsequent popups or if the same one is just hidden and reshown.  If this is the case, you might need a [CallWndProc hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644975(VS.85).aspx), to get `WM_SHOWWINDOW` messages.

**Edit:**

I should mention that the hooks that I've mentioned cannot be implemented in .NET.  Except for the low-level keyboard and mouse hooks, global system hooks must be implemented in a native (unmanaged) DLL.  Windows will load this DLL into other processes, and if a managed DLL gets loaded into a process that doesn't have the .NET CLR loaded, it will crash that process.  (Even if the CLR is loaded, it might be at a different address, also causing a crash.)

So you must build your hooks in a native (unmanaged) DLL.  It's possible to interface from here to a managed application, such as [Michael Kennedy has done on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalsystemhook.aspx), but to do it properly, and handle the hook types I've mentioned above, you'd need to use interprocess communication, a step that Michael Kennedy left out.  All in all, for the purpose you've described, it would probably be easier to just build the whole thing in native code.

Comment: I like the idea of using a hook - better than my suggestion to use polling. Presumably this would only work in unmanaged code though?

Comment: @andyjohnson:  Yes, in fact this is important and I'll update my answer to make this clear.